# Minimum specification for Haskell library type classes?

Tags: haskell

The Haskell prelude and Standard Library define a number of useful type classes.

Is there a page somewhere that lists the minimum complete definition for all these classes?

Comment: Can you quantify what you mean by "standard library"? Are you referring to haskell98/haskell2010/base? GHC's boot libraries? Haskell Platform?

Comment: ivanm, I'm not sure I know enough to know the difference.  I just wanted to make any answer would include things like Monad and Arrow.

Comment: You could rephrase it as something like "What is the minimum specification for the common Haskell type classes?".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This information can be found scattered around the Haskell language report as well as the GHC documentation, but in the interest of having an overview, I'm starting a CW answer for this.

## Comparison

- [**Eq**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Eq):
  `==` or `/=`.
- [**Ord**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Ord):
  `compare` or `<=`.

## Numbers

- [**Num**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Num):
  All except either `-` or `negate`.
- [**Real**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Real):
  `toRational`.
- [**Integral**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Integral):
  `quotRem` and `toInteger`.
- [**Bits**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Bits.html#t:Bits):
  `.&.`, `.|.`, `xor`, `complement`, either `shift` or both `shiftL` and `shiftR`, either `rotate` or both `rotateL` and `rotateR`, `bitSize` and `isSigned`.
- [**Fractional**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Fractional):
  `fromRational` and either `/` or `recip`.
- [**Floating**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Floating):
  `pi`, `exp`, `log`, `sin`, `cos`, `sinh`, `cosh`, `asin`, `acos`, `atan`, `asinh`, `acosh` and `atanh`.
- [**RealFrac**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac):
  `properFraction`.
- [**RealFloat**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:RealFloat):
  All except `exponent`, `significand`, `scaleFloat` and `atan2`.

## Functors

- [**Functor**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Functor):
  `fmap`.
- [**Applicative**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative):
  `pure` and `<*>`.
- [**Monad**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Monad):
  `>>=` and `return`.
- [**MonadPlus**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus):
  `mplus` and `mzero`.
- [**MonadFix**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad-Fix.html#t:MonadFix):
  `mfix`.
- [**Foldable**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable):
  `foldMap` or `foldr`.
- [**Traversable**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable): `traverse` or `sequenceA`.

## Arrows

- [**Category**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Category.html#t:Category):
  `.` and `id`.
- [**Arrow**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:Arrow):
  `arr` and `first`.
- [**ArrowZero**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowZero):
  `zeroArrow`.
- [**ArrowPlus**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowPlus):
  `<+>`.
- [**ArrowChoice**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice):
  `left`.
- [**ArrowApply**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowApply):
  `app`.
- [**ArrowLoop**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowLoop):
  `loop`.

## Serialization

- [**Read**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Read):
  `readsPrec` (or, for GHC only, `readPrec`).
- [**Show**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Show):
  `show` or `showsPrec`.

## Misc

- [**Enum**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Enum):
  `toEnum` and `fromEnum`.
- [**Bounded**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Bounded):
  Both `minBound` and `maxBound`.
- [**Ix**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ix.html#t:Ix):
  `range`, `index`, `inRange`.
- [**Monoid**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid):
  `mempty` and `mappend`.

Comment: `Enum` and `Bounded` don't really belong under the heading 'Numbers'. Has anybody a good idea under what heading(s) they could be subsumed?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Agreed. I put them under "Misc" together with Monoid. Feel free to move stuff around if you have a better suggestion.

Comment: By the way, I suggest we keep it to the classes in `base`. That should cover the most common ones.

Answer (score 2):

The section in the Haskell Report about [standard classes](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#sect6.3) describes what you need to implement for each type class.